# Can we tidy up Adaptation?

Tags: discussion

We've got [adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation), [book-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-adaptation), [comic-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comic-adaptation), [video-game-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-game-adaptation) and [play-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play-adaptation).

Some tag wiki's are filled in, some are just the usage. It's unclear if the specific tags should be used with [adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation) and not all usage blurbs are consistent as to whether the tags are for works that are adapted, or about the process of adaptation itself.

What should we do to improve it?

Comment: `adaptation` was left alive as kind of a fallback for adaptations that aren't coming from books, comics, games or plays. It's not really to be used together with them. But I agree its existence isn't really optimal. But the questions are *always* about the adaptation process and never just about films that happen to be adaptations, so I guess some tag excerpts (specifically video game and general adaptation) could use some refinement.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I made an edit to the video game tag, please take a look